# Flutter -> glass effect over google maps?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a scaffold -> stack -> google maps, some buttons, and a BackdropFilter.
In a test page without google maps, the filter fuzzies out everything as expected.
However, when you have a GoogleMap in the stack, everything else but the map gets fuzzied or filtered.

The backdrop filter is a simple affair:

```
BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                    ),
```

I can almost understand why...and yet here I am.

[image]

Comment: This looks like the same issue in github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56789.